# How to sum columns with same date in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum

I have an array with these type of data inside it, and I need to sum up the columns with same date.

```
[["01-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0], ["02-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 130, 0, 0, 0], ["03-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0], ["10-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 100, 0, 0, 0], ["02-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 70, 0, 0], ["10-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 100, 0, 0], ["11-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 110, 0, 0], ["12-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 120, 0, 0], ["09-04-2013", 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 130, 0], ["17-04-2013", 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 30, 0], ["15-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 17], ["17-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 90], ["18-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 100]]
```

How can I do it in ruby? I meant to sum up the rows with the same date into one row, and if there is no duplicated date, keep the old ones.

Comment: Is this coming from a database? If so, it may be better done in ActiveRecord/SQL.

Comment: This is array set up from Search result. I need to prepair array of data for Google ComboChart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aggregated_rows = rows.group_by(&:first).map do |date, rows_by_date|
  values = rows_by_date.transpose.drop(1).map { |xs| xs.reduce(:+) }
  [date, values]
end

#[["01-04-2013", [100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0]],
# ["02-04-2013", [200.0, 250.0, 130, 70, 0, 0]],
...
# ["18-04-2013", [100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 100]]]
```

Comment: Yeah this is what i wanted! 
 
I made some adjustments. 
aggregated_rows = @tmp.group_by(&:first).map do |date, rs|
  values = rs[0].zip(*rs[1..-1]).drop(1).map { |xs| xs.reduce(:+) }
  [date, values].flatten
end

One more thing, do you know how to divide only 2 first columns ?

Comment: I mean to divide only 2 first columns by number of duplications for date.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'pp'
require 'matrix'

d = [["01-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0], ["02-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 130, 0, 0, 0], ["03-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0], ["10-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 100, 0, 0, 0], ["02-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 70, 0, 0], ["10-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 100, 0, 0], ["11-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 110, 0, 0], ["12-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 120, 0, 0], ["09-04-2013", 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 130, 0], ["17-04-2013", 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 30, 0], ["15-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 17], ["17-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 90], ["18-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 100]]

pp(
  d.group_by(&:first).values.reject do |v|
    v.size <= 1
  end.map do |e|
    e.inject do |m, e|
      (Vector.[](*m) + Vector.[](*e)).to_a
    end
  end
)
```

*Update after comments:*

```
  d.group_by(&:first).values.map do |e|
    e.inject do |m, e|
      [e[0], (Vector.[](*m[1..-1]) + Vector.[](*e[1..-1])).to_a].flatten
    end
  end.sort
```

*Specification change alert:*

```
def v m
  Vector.[](*m.drop(1))
end

d.group_by(&:first).values.map do |group|
  r = group.inject do |m, e|
    [e[0], *(v(m) + v(e)).to_a]
  end
  r[1] /= group.size
  r[2] /= group.size
  r
end.sort
```

---

<sup>**Note.** 
I'm not saying this is homework, but in the cases that are, it should be obvious that when we just do it for the students, we are not really doing them any favors, right?  Plus, this solution is provided on a public site that is instantly indexed by google and, being in the top 100 sites *in the world*, it is not exactly a secret to the prof or the grader. And what if the school is using a national database like http://turnitin.com/ ? I suppose they could check public code snippets if they wanted to. And finally, there is some rather well-written code posted on SO by the, ahem, hobbyists. I'm not sure it can typically pass for lower-division intro-course original work, if I, ahem, say so myself. :-)</sup>

Comment: Thx for quick answer, thing is this one sums up dates too. Also i ment to sum up the ones with a date being same and keeping not sumed the ones without duplicated date.

Comment: Thanks this workis great too! In this example i need one more thing, it would be dividing first 2 values of and array where duplication occures by number of duplications. 

EXAMPLE:
`code ["02-04-2013", 200.0, 250.0, 130, 70, 0, 0]`
would give 
`code ["02-04-2013", 100.0, 125.0, 130, 70, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'pp'

a = [["01-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0], ["02-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 130, 0, 0, 0], ["03-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0], ["10-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 100, 0, 0, 0], ["02-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 70, 0, 0], ["10-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 100, 0, 0], ["11-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 110, 0, 0], ["12-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 120, 0, 0], ["09-04-2013", 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 130, 0], ["17-04-2013", 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 30, 0], ["15-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 17], ["17-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 90], ["18-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 100]]
h = {}
a.group_by(&:first).each{|k,v| v.flatten!.delete(k); h[k] = v.inject(:+)}
pp h
```

***output:***

```
{"01-04-2013"=>330.0,
 "02-04-2013"=>650.0,
 "03-04-2013"=>330.0,
 "10-04-2013"=>650.0,
 "11-04-2013"=>350.0,
 "12-04-2013"=>360.0,
 "09-04-2013"=>130.0,
 "17-04-2013"=>350.0,
 "15-04-2013"=>247.0,
 "18-04-2013"=>330.0}
```

---

```
pp a.group_by(&:first).map{|k,v| v.flatten!.uniq!}
```

***Output:***

```
[["01-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0],
 ["02-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 130, 0, 140.0, 70],
 ["03-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0],
 ["10-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 100, 0, 140.0],
 ["11-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 110],
 ["12-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 120],
 ["09-04-2013", 0.0, 0, 130],
 ["17-04-2013", 0.0, 0, 30, 100.0, 130.0, 90],
 ["15-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 17],
 ["18-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 100]]
```

---

```
pp a.group_by(&:first).map{|k,v|  v.transpose.map!{|a| a.inject(:+)}}
```

***Output:***

```
[["01-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0],
 ["02-04-201302-04-2013", 200.0, 250.0, 130, 70, 0, 0],
 ["03-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0],
 ["10-04-201310-04-2013", 200.0, 250.0, 100, 100, 0, 0],
 ["11-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 110, 0, 0],
 ["12-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 120, 0, 0],
 ["09-04-2013", 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 130, 0],
 ["17-04-201317-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 30, 90],
 ["15-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 17],
 ["18-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 100]]
```

Comment: i need something like this :
`code  [["01-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0], ["02-04-2013", 200.0, 250.0, 130, 70, 0, 0], ["03-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0], ["10-04-2013", 200.0, 250.0, 100, 100, 0, 0], ["11-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 110, 0, 0], ["12-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 120, 0, 0], ["09-04-2013", 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 130, 0], ["17-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 30, 90], ["15-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 17], ["18-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 100]]`

And now i need to divide the 2 columns of those rows which are duplicated

Comment: in this example it would be 200.0 and 250.0 for "02-04-2013" divided by 2

Comment: @user2305252 couldn't get you

Comment: I need to divide first two values of duplicated date row: `code ["02-04-2013", 200.0, 250.0, 130, 70, 0, 0]` 

So if there is duplication on a date we sum up all the values than divide first two by number of duplications.

Comment: So in this example it would be `code ["02-04-2013", 100.0, 125.0, 130, 70, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [["01-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0], ["02-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 130, 0, 0, 0], ["03-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0], ["10-04-2013", 100.0, 110.0, 100, 0, 0, 0], ["02-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 70, 0, 0], ["10-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 100, 0, 0], ["11-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 110, 0, 0], ["12-04-2013", 100.0, 140.0, 0, 120, 0, 0], ["09-04-2013", 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 130, 0], ["17-04-2013", 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 30, 0], ["15-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 17], ["17-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 90], ["18-04-2013", 100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 100]]

require "pp"

def group_and_sum_rows_by_date_string(a)
    # instantiate a hash that returns an empty array for a key
    # that doesn't exist
    h = Hash.new([])
    a.each do |row|
        # populate the hash with date string as key, and array of 
        # arrays of the values for that date string
        h[k=row.shift] = ([row] + h[k]).compact
    end
    # add up all the corresponding values in each element's array
    # arrays, and return the result as an array
    h.map{|k, v| [k, v.transpose.map{|x| x.inject(:+)}]}
end

pp group_and_sum_rows_by_date_string(a)

[["15-04-2013", [100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 17]],
 ["03-04-2013", [100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0]],
 ["02-04-2013", [200.0, 250.0, 130, 70, 0, 0]],
 ["17-04-2013", [100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 30, 90]],
 ["18-04-2013", [100.0, 130.0, 0, 0, 0, 100]],
 ["09-04-2013", [0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 130, 0]],
 ["01-04-2013", [100.0, 110.0, 120, 0, 0, 0]],
 ["12-04-2013", [100.0, 140.0, 0, 120, 0, 0]],
 ["10-04-2013", [200.0, 250.0, 100, 100, 0, 0]],
 ["11-04-2013", [100.0, 140.0, 0, 110, 0, 0]]]
```